# If app was bundled via Fastlane, it crash on startup

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane

I'm currently deploying to testflight via fastlane which works perfectly fine. But when I go to download the app from testflight and open it, it just crashes without any particular warning.

Note: It works fine on my local machine when I run it on the simulator.

Here is my current fastlane file:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"

  lane :beta do

    git_pull
    ensure_git_status_clean
    get_certificates           # invokes cert - must be installed locally in your mac-keychain
    get_provisioning_profile   # invokes sigh - must be installed locally in your mac-keychain


    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "test.xcodeproj")
   
    #run a build
    build_app(workspace: "test.xcworkspace", scheme: "TestProj")

    upload_to_testflight
    slack(
           message: "Successfully distributed a new beta build",
           success: true,
           slack_url: "mywebhook"
       )
  end
end
```

Comment: Think it's something to do with my release build working on a solution!

Comment: Can you please download your IPA from Testflight and run it at your IOS Emulator or connected Iphone while open the DeviceLogs? (It should be in Xcode ⇒ Window ⇒ Devices. There you should see what's really happen at your device and what's the cause of the crash/error.